# Create pdf using flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, alivepdf

I am trying to create PDF file using flex.

There are some problem which i am facing..

when i have less text to display it's working fine. but when there are lots of text which have to display it's overlap.

is there any PDF component which is expand according to the display text.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to create a PDF?  Or display one? Can you share any code?

Comment: I want to create pdf,But Text will be display in pdf file

Comment: How is your PDF created? Which library do you use? Is it created server-side?

Comment: i am using AlivePDF.swc for desktop application. i did not use any server side technology.

Answer (score 1):

Enjoy creating .pdf file using this code

```
import org.alivepdf.pdf.PDF;  
import org.alivepdf.saving.Method;   
import org.alivepdf.fonts.*;   
import org.alivepdf.pages.Page;   
import org.alivepdf.display.Display;   
import org.alivepdf.layout.*; 

private var pdf:PDF;  
private var file:File; 
[Embed( source="bg.jpg", mimeType="application/octet-stream" )]  
private var pngBytes:Class; 

public function generate ():void  
{ 
    var pdf:PDF = new PDF( Orientation.PORTRAIT, Unit.MM, Size.A4 ); 
    pdf.setDisplayMode( Display.FULL_PAGE, Layout.SINGLE_PAGE );
    var newPage:Page = new Page ( Orientation.PORTRAIT, Unit.MM, Size.A4 );
    pdf.addPage( newPage );
    pdf.setFont(FontFamily.ARIAL , Style.NORMAL, 12);
    pdf.addText("This is a sample text",5,15);
    pdf.drawCircle(25,35,15);
    pdf.addPage();
    pdf.addImageStream( new pngBytes() as ByteArray );
    var fs:FileStream = new FileStream();  
    file = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("testPage.pdf");   
    fs.open( file, FileMode.WRITE);   
    var bytes:ByteArray = pdf.save(Method.LOCAL);   
    fs.writeBytes(bytes);   
    fs.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use **"AlivePDF"** to generate PDF from Flex.

AlivePDF is a client side AS3 PDF generation library for Adobe Flash, Flex and AIR. It is a Open source library.

### Library File and Documentation

http://code.google.com/p/alivepdf/
http://code.google.com/p/alivepdf/downloads/list

### Reference

http://alivepdf.bytearray.org/

Comment: I am using same process..but whenever my text content is more than a page. i am not able to add page exactly when one page text is finish and add another page.

Comment: You can try this code : 
var myPDF:PDF = new PDF( Orientation.LANDSCAPE, Unit.MM, Size.A4); myPDF.setDisplayMode ( Display.DEFAULT); myPDF.addPage(); myPDF.setMargins(10,10,10,10);